# Manifest merger failed error, build fails

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

I am receiving the following error code:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-33:19 to override.
```

and below is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.buddy_finder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AccountSetUp"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityFeedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am trying to use the CropImageActivity and followed the instructions given in the GitHub page and will attach the link [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/wiki/Using-built-in-CropImageActivity)

Comment: try this:  Added two lines in gradle.properties file:

`android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to `<application>` element at `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your project like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

And add this lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

If it does not solve your issue, add this line to application element of your manifest file:

```
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

and probably you need to replace all android support dependencies with androidx ones in build.gradle file.

For example like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
```

Comment: If my answer solve your issue please give me upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add **tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"** to application element in your manifest